# Where does Laravel register its models

Tags: php, laravel

You create a Laravel project and you have models. At some stage you decide you need to change the file name of a model but changing it makes it unusable. So somewhere Laravel must save the name of the model. Cause changing the name doesn't work but deleting it and creating a new model works. Where does Laravel store the names of models you created using artisan so you can just change it there without needing to create a new model?

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpautoload`?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel model isn't more than a normal php Class that extends `namespace Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class , by default it will be mapped to the database table that uses the same name (model name is singular, table name is plural)
EX: the model `Post` will be mapped to the table `posts`

you can also customize the mapped database table name by overriding the property `$table` :

```php
protected $table = 'table_name'
```

no need to register laravel models anywhere